# Google Sheets script to merge identical values of a column when a row is added

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge

I manage a table and I have a tab that is the equivalent of an account statement.

I use a script that allows me to merge all the cells of identical value in a column that I execute manually.

In a table B28:N, ordered by date(B), whose range B28:M is filled via several imports with QUERY, the column B contains dates of operation and the column N takes the month and the year of the date of the column B with a formula in ARRAYFORMULA in N27. Here it is:

```
={"Période / Mois";ARRAYFORMULA(SI($B$26:$B<>"";TEXTE($B26:$B;"mmm")&CAR(10)&TEXTE($B$26:$B;"yyy");""))}
```

My problem is that when the cells in column M are merged correctly and a row is added and I run the script, the merge is done in a weird way.

I would like that automatically when a new row is added, the script cancels the merge, merges again, and reformats the horizontals lines.

[Here is my sheet (problem on the " BANQUE " tab)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xJjJ0LQP9-lX2zod6brUElRj835fH4uNqvCOTtvr7A/edit#gid=977291266)

Here is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var start = 28; // Start row number for values.
  var c = {};
  var k = "";
  var offset = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var getSheetByName = "BANQUE";

  // Retrieve values of column B.
  var data = ss.getRange(start, 14, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String);

  // Retrieve the number of duplication values.
  data.forEach(function(e){c[e[0]] = c[e[0]] ? c[e[0]] + 1 : 1;});

  // Merge cells.
  data.forEach(function(e){
    if (k != e[0]) {
      ss.getRange(start + offset, 14, c[e[0]], 1).merge();
      offset += c[e[0]];
    }
    k = e[0];
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By script

```
function mergeCells() {
  const columns = [14]; // These column number is the column "N"
  const sheetName = "BANQUE";  // Please set the sheetname.
  const firstRow = 28
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const rng = sheet.getRange(firstRow, columns, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow, 1)
  rng.getMergedRanges().forEach(m => m.breakApart())
  const data = rng.getValues().flat()
  let toThere = data.length - 1
  let fromHere = 0
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (data[i] != data[i - 1]) {
      sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, columns, toThere - i + 1, 1).activate().merge()
      toThere = i - 1
    }
  }
  i = 0
  sheet.getRange(firstRow + i, columns, toThere - i + 1, 1).activate().merge()
}
```

for automation, add this code at the beginning of the present onEdt(e) function

```
  let sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  let onglets = ['PAIEMENTS', 'ENCAUSSEMENTS', 'IMPORTS']
  if (onglets.indexOf(sh.getName()!=-1)){
    mergeCells()
  }
```

Comment: This script work good but only to merge. What I would like is that automatically when a new row is added, the script cancels the merge, merges again, and reformats the vertical separation lines.

Comment: I think we should add just before this mergeCells function a function that would reset the range to the default format and then execute mergeCells

Comment: already done with `.breakApart()`

Comment: if the row is added automatically, you can't use onEdit, but you can add at the end of the automation this function (useless whith CF)

Comment: Okay, so I don't understand when I add a line nothing happens

Comment: how does this line is added ?

Comment: Range M28:M5003

Comment: But my first script only merges lines with a value

Comment: in fact, the use of arrayformula in N27, N28:N depends on a large function in B28 that takes information from payments/cash-ins/imports. So you have to apply onEdit to any changes in these tabs (but this can probably slow down the behavior of the file). onEdit only works with manual changes.

Comment: Okay, so is there a way to automate without onEdit()?

Comment: done, see the updated answer

Comment: Il faut simplement ajouter "()" après mergeCells like this mergeCells()

Comment: yes you are right, thx for the correction

Answer (score 1):

With conditional formatting (there are many advantages: the data base remains fully usable, you can query, sort, ...)

odd months, first occurrence

```
=and(N28<>N27;mod(month($B28);2))
```

even months, first occurrence

```
=and(N28<>N27;mod(month($B28);2))
```

odd months (background color and font color are the same)

```
=mod(month($B28);2)
```

even months (background color and font color are the same)

```
=mod(month($B28)+1;2)
```

assuming there is at least one item per month

[image]

it is possible to center the text (+/- one row) but much more complicated

Comment: It can be useful but I really want to make this script work

Comment: I added an onEdit() function in my script but it doesn't work. Maybe because I already have an onEdit() function in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that unmerges, merges and adds the horizontal lines.

I haven't found a way to automate it yet so I added the onOpen() function.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Période / Mois Banque', 'mergeBanque')
    .addToUi();
  mergeBanque()
}

function mergeBanque() {
  var start = 28; // Start row number for values.
  var c = {};
  var k = "";
  var offset = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('BANQUE'); // Please set the sheetname

  // unmerge column B. Add horizontal SOLID borders column B. Retrieve values of column B.
  var data = ss.getRange(start, 14, ss.getLastRow(), 1)
  .breakApart()
  .setBorder(null, null, null, null, null, true, 'black', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
  .getValues().filter(String);

  // Retrieve the number of duplication values.
  data.forEach(function(e){c[e[0]] = c[e[0]] ? c[e[0]] + 1 : 1;});

  // Merge cells.
  data.forEach(function(e){
    if (k != e[0]) {
      ss.getRange(start + offset, 14, c[e[0]], 1).merge(); // column to be merged "14"
      offset += c[e[0]];
    }
    k = e[0];
  });
}
```